# SOAnswerDate - answer dates in user profiles!

Tags: script

#### Notice: This feature has been officially rolled out, and so this user-script is no longer necessary. It shall remain here, though, for reputation's sake :)

Simply put, this adds answer dates to the profile page on most stackexchange sites:

[image]

I don't know what else to say, so here's the script:

## [Click to install me!](https://raw.github.com/richardjrossiii/Stack-Overflow-User-Scripts/master/SOAnswerDate.user.js) <sub>([view source](https://github.com/richardjrossiii/Stack-Overflow-User-Scripts/blob/master/SOAnswerDate.user.js?dontgreasemonkey=true))</sub>